# how to use react material ui component in plain vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

**Problem statement**

> 1. so I have a plain javascript project  and I have been assigned to that
>    project to do some modifications in that application,
> 2. they want to use react component in their plain javascript application.
> 3. so I have to replace all buttons in the plain javascript application with react component (I can used material UI button ) and
>    all card and header components also have to be replaced.
> 4. condition is no need to  create new react application, use existing javascript application and do some modifications

```js
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML= `<div>
<div id = 'button'><div>
</div>`

document.getElementById('button').innerHTML= `<button>click me</button>`;
```

```html
<button>hello</button>
<div id = 'container'></div>
```

Comment: you can't. Material UI is a react framework. 

if you just want to add material looking buttons to your vanilla application, try something like [materialize](https://materializecss.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Material UI is a react framework.

If you just want to add material looking buttons to your vanilla application, try something like [materialize](https://materializecss.com/).